# Reliable way to prove that int++ is not atomic

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I can already see it's not by the incorrect increments, but there's just one small piece of the puzzle I can't quite seem to catch.

We have the following code:

```
internal class StupidObject
{
    static public SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 100);

    private int counter;

    public bool MethodCall() => counter++ == 0;

    public int GetCounter() => counter;
}
```

And the following test code to try and see if it's an atomic operation:

```
var sharedObj = new StupidObject();
var resultTasks = new Task[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    resultTasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await StupidObject.semaphore.WaitAsync();
        if (sharedObj.MethodCall())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        };
    });
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");

Console.ReadLine();


StupidObject.semaphore.Release(100);

Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(sharedObj.GetCounter());

Console.ReadLine();
```

I expect to see multiple `True`'s written to the console, but I ever see a single one.

Why is that? By my understanding, a `++` operation reads the value, increments the **read** value, and then stores that value to the variable.

Those are 3 operations. If we had a race condition, where thread `A` did the following:

- Reads value to be `0`.
- Increments **read** value by `1`.

And another thread `B` did the same things, but beat thread `A` to the third operation as following:

- Writes **read** value to variable.

When `A` finishes writing the incremented read value, it should print back `0`, same with thread `B` after it has done its write operation.

Am I missing something at the design aspect of things, or is my test not good enough to make this exact situation come to fruition?

Example without the Task Parallel Library (still yields a single `True` to the console):

```
var sharedObj = new StupidObject();
var resultTasks = new Thread[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    resultTasks[i] = new Thread(() =>
    {
        StupidObject.semaphore.Wait();
        if (sharedObj.MethodCall())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        };
    });
    resultTasks[i].IsBackground = false;
    resultTasks[i].Start();
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");

Console.ReadLine();


StupidObject.semaphore.Release(10000);
```

Comment: Are you writing a unit test to test `int` itself? Why?

Comment: The simple existence of [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int32__) and the assumption that the framework developers didn't create it just to trick unwary beginners should be enough for most people.

Comment: Nonsensical proof int++ isn't atomic https://dotnetfiddle.net/bWzKPa (Better as a comment)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm pretty sure that InterlockedIncrement was created to increment interlocked locks! https://c8.alamy.com/comp/CC8FAN/zwei-zahlenschlsser-gegenseitig-verschlossen-two-combination-locks-CC8FAN.jpg :D

Comment: @TheGeneral after about fifteen runs, by mere chance I actually got a value of zero!

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 hah, I call that a win!

Answer (score 1):

What **Liam** said about Console.WriteLine is possible, but also there's another thing.

Starting Tasks doesn't equal starting threads, and even starting threads doesn't guarantee that all threads will begin immediatelly. Starting 100 short tasks probably won't even fill .Net's thread pool significantly, because those tasks end quickly and thread pool's manager **probably** won't start more than 3-5 threads. That's not the "immediate" and "parallel" you'd like to see when you want to start parallel 100 increments to race with each other, right? Remember that Tasks are queued first, then assigned to threads.

Note that the StupidObject's counter starts with zero and that's the ONLY MOMENT EVER that the value is zero. If ANY thread wins the race and successfully writes an update to that integer, you'll get FALSE in all future tasks, because it's already `1`.

And if there are many tasks on the thread pool's queue, something first  has to notice that fact. At program's start, thread pool lacks threads. They are not started in dozens right at program start. They are started on demand. **Most probably** you fill up the queue with 100 tasks, threadpool's thread is created, picks first task, bumps counter to 1, then **maybe** thread pool starts new threads to consume tasks faster.

To get a bit better image what's happening, instead of printing out 'true', collect values observed by `return counter++`: let each task run, finish, store its value in Task's `.Result`, then run threads/tasks, then wait for all of then to stop, then collect .Results and write a histogram of those values. Even if you don't see 5 zeros, maybe you will see 3 ones, 7 twos, 2 threes and so on.

Comment: `If ANY thread wins the race and successfully writes an update to that integer, you'll get FALSE in all future tasks, because it's already 1.` -> Is that really the case though? doesn't a `++` operation work the way I described? Because if it does, then more than one thread can and should print the same initially read value.

Comment: @SpiritBob but when the "other threads" would read the initial value? They won't do that at Task's creation. Only object reference to StupidObject is captured. The only moment when threads inspect the value is when x++ is actually executed, and that reads 'x' at **that** moment. But WHEN is it? When program starts, you ONLY have the main thread that creates and fires off tasks. When first Task.Run is called, first thread is created and is free to run immediatelly. Or a moment after. And you've got a management race: will Main manage to run more than one thread BEFORE first thread does x++?

Comment: @SpiritBob:(continuing) and as I wrote, it's even worse, because starting a task doesn't equal starting a thread. Sure, when first task is created, a moment later a thread is created to handle it. But other tasks will probably be queued. And now you have 2 tasks: main, and one on the thread pool. Nohting more. 99.99% chance of other thread waking up and doing x++ before threadpool detects a stall and decides to start more tasks.

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim` is the best shot you've got at creating a race condition. You prepare the threads to synchronize, and then release them all at the same time to race.

When thread `A` reaches the `++` operation, it starts doing each of its operations one by one.

When another thread beats thread `A`'s 3 operations, both threads should yield a return of `0`. You can see in more detail what I'm trying to explain here in my initial question.

Comment: I've also included an example with long-living threads.

Comment: @SpiritBob: nope, nope, and nope. Stop assuming you can control thread's timings. You can not. The OS screws any of your plans. You can create 100 threads on a 100-core machine, and yeah, at SOME point they MAYBE will be all parallel. (A)how long does X++ take? one cycle? (B)loop&create thread takes time earlier threads can run (C)barrier-like WILL NOT ensure that threads start AT THE SAME TIME, barrier-like only ALLOWS THEM to run. The OS still decides which thread to wake, and the OS still has to wake them. Now the create or wakeup loop is in the OS not in your code, but it's still there.

Comment: I never said it's perfect, I only said it's your best shot at doing it with the tools you've been given. Of course you can go ahead and ditch everything c# comes bundled with, and even create your own OS to handle the issues you're describing.

Comment: @SpiritBob: think about what I said about histogram, and think why do YOU consider the zero to be more important than 8? Why not try observing how many 8s are there? Seeing several zeros is just the same missed-update as any other missed-update. No magic lies in the zero. Now, if you are really fixed on that zero, then your best chance is some sort of `volatile bool GO_NOW=false` and create 100 threads with spin-wait `while(!GO_NOW) { nothing;}` then `x++` right after that busy-spinning. Never allow threads to sleep, keep them busy, maybe they will break out while together.

Comment: oh, yeah, and setting thread's affinity to different cores, and making them high-prio may also help in ensuring that the OS keeps them on parallel cores and doesn't pause them on that critical few-nanoseconds time of your program making the first x++ ever, just to play some youtube on that core.. but still, there's no guarantee, just increased probability.